# Intercom not working on android 12 Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-12, intercom

io.intercom.android.sdk.fcm.IntercomFcmMessengerService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present]

I know I have to add something in the manifest similar to this but still not finding it

```
 <receiver android:name="" android:exported="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
      </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android 11 and lower, when declaring an `Activity`, `Service`, or `Broadcast` receiver in `AndroidManifest`, you did not explicitly declare `android:exported`. Since the default value is `exported=true`, you only need to declare `exported=false` when you do not want to disclose to the outside.

For example:

```
 <activity android:name="com.example.app.backgroundService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.START_BACKGROUND" />
    </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Android 12 Changes: Explicit declaration of exported Apps that set SDK API 31 (android 12) as Target sdk on Android 12 devices must explicitly declare exported in components such as Activity that declared intent-filter.

For example,you must explicitly declare exported as follows:

```
  <service android:name="com.example.app.backgroundService"
         android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.app.START_BACKGROUND" />
    </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

In a word, `android:exported="true"` or `"android:exported="false"` must be added to all `receivers`, `services`, and `activity` tags with intent-filters inside them.

**Note:**

You can find the `AndroidManifest.xml` in folder `obj` of your app. My Folder is `MyAndroidProject\obj\Debug\120\`.

After finding file `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can recheck if you have added tag `android:exported` to all of your `receivers`, `services`, and `activity`.